# JSF 2 nested composite component, passing f:validateLength

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, nested, facelets, composite-component

I am trying to create a series of nested components, where standard jsf/primefaces components are wrapped in standard markup and can still receive standard facet attributes etc

I am having trouble in the following code with f:validateLength getting applied to the specified field.

```
<util:reducedwrap id="baz" label="Baz">
    <f:validateLength minimum="3" for="value" />
</util:reducedwrap>
```

### reducedwrap.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/util">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="fld" />
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <util:reducedwrapper label="#{cc.attrs.label}">
        <h:inputText id="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    </util:reducedwrapper>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedwrapper.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel for="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <cc:insertChildren />
    <h:message for="fld" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

However, while the f:validateLength is going awol and so h:message does not see "fld", h:outputLabel does and ends up being output with the correctly generated for attribute. (This confuses me - which is right? Both?)

Is the value I am using for the "for" attribute of f:validateLength (or indeed h:message) wrong? And if so, what should it be?

---

I have further reduced the code so that all the nested stuff either happens in the called component (util:reduced) or is called directly from it (util:reducedsplit). This code (along with a sample page calling them) follows at the end of this message.

Both work as I expect, but neither seem to be an ideal solution.

util:reduced obviously demands replication of the code in any further components using this pattern.

util:reducedsplit works, and although I could live with inserting 2 components in further components, I am unable to move any wrapping markup (which I do actuallty have) to the components due to validity considerations. so that would need to be duplicated in any case.

Which takes me back to wondering how to make util:reducedwrap work as I want

Or should I go to the custom component route?

Reduced code follows:

### reducedcomposite.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/util">
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="default">
            util:reduced<br />
            <util:reduced id="foo" label="Foo">
                <f:validateLength minimum="5" for="value" />
            </util:reduced>
            <hr />
            util:reducedsplit<br />
            <util:reducedsplit id="bar" label="Bar">
                <f:validateLength minimum="4" for="value" />
            </util:reducedsplit>
            <hr />
            util:reducedwrap<br />
            <util:reducedwrap id="baz" label="Baz">
                <f:validateLength minimum="3" for="value" />
            </util:reducedwrap>
            <hr /> 
            <h:commandButton value="Do it!" />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

util components   (/resources/components/util)

### reduced.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="fld" />
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel for="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <h:inputText id="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    <h:message for="fld" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedsplit.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/util">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="fld" />
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <util:reducedlabel label="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <h:inputText id="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    <util:reducedmessage />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedlabel.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" >
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel for="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedmessage.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" >
<cc:interface>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:message for="fld" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedwrap.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:util="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components/util">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="id"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="fld" />
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <util:reducedwrapper label="#{cc.attrs.label}">
        <h:inputText id="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"/>
    </util:reducedwrapper>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

### reducedwrapper.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="label"/>
</cc:interface>   
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLabel for="fld" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <cc:insertChildren />
    <h:message for="fld" />
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the "for" attribute of your validator to the id of you component input ("fld")? I have a similar situation here.

Answer (score 0):

better late than never, you need this:

```
<composite:interface>
    ...
   <composite:editableValueHolder name="value" targets="inputText" />
    ...
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    ...
   <h:inputText id="inputText" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

Suppose the component is called "inputText" and your would use it in the traditional way:

```
<util:inputText value="#{beanName.valueForInput}">
    <f:validateLength minimum="10" />
</util:inputText>
```